# @BeforeClass and @AfterClass in testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have designed a framework in which there is a `Base Class` which set the browser

```
public class BasePage{

  public WebDriver driver;
     @BeforeClass
     //opens the browser before each class is executed
     public void setBrowser() {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      }
     //closes the browser after each class is executed
     @AfterClass
      public void closeBrowser() {
          driver.quit();

      }
    }
```

All the TC , such as `A, B` inherit this `Base Class`, Opens the browser and performs the action. For Ex :

```
public class A extends BasePage{
        //Login to the application
        @Test 
        public void fun1()
        {
            LoginLogout lp=new LoginLogout(driver);
            lp.login(driver);
        }
    }


public class B extends BasePage{
        //Login to the application
        @Test 
        public void fun1()
        {
            LoginLogout lp=new LoginLogout(driver);
            lp.login(driver);
        }
    }
```

Now while running the test case : When Class A is executing , if i close the browser even Class B is not run. If the execution runs normally, then for each class browser is opened and closed properly.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: In between execution , if the browser gets closed then the next test case is not executed. How do i prevent this? Ex Class A, Class B , Class C execute in order. While Execution of Class B , browser get closed. Then Class C execution is also skipped.

Comment: Each test is running independently. If one of them fails or interrupted it shouldn't effect the other one. There is missing data in your description. Please tell  **exactly** what is happening in this scenario.

Comment: Do you close the browser manually?

Comment: How are you trigerring your tests Neha?  Are the tests in different classes?

Comment: @Niharika All these test are in different classes. So ClassA is one test case having test annotation. Class B is another Test Case having test annotation. Each test case extends BaseClass as mentioned above.

Comment: I tried closing the browser in the middle of the execution just to check that the next test case is not impacted.

Comment: How are you trigerring the test?

Comment: I am running through a jar file. The code has a main method as below:                                               public static void main(String[] args) {  
  TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
  TestNG testng = new TestNG();
  List<String> suites1 = Lists.newArrayList();
  String xmlLoc="C:\\Input\\testng.xml";
  System.out.println(xmlLoc);
  suites1.add(xmlLoc);//path to xml.
  testng.addListener(tla);
  testng.setTestSuites(suites1);
  testng.run();
}

Comment: @Neha - A basic question.. How are you ascertaining that you are indeed closing the browser for Test A and not for Test B ? BeforeClass and AfterClass annotations will be executed for every test class that gets instantiated. You can try setting "configfailurepolicy" to "continue" in your suite xml file and see if that helps. This attribute basically forces TestNG to invoke the config methods even if they failed once.

Comment: Take a look at this gist (https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/65847122ba41ee485f72ab4e920d4436) that kind of demonstrates your problem. Only difference between your example and mine is that I am programmatically always failing the config method, but in your case you are failing the method randomly via manual intervention.